# Integral in d-dimensions

Tags: integration

Maybe it is an easy integral but I don't know how to compute it. In fact I think I have to use polar coordinates but I don't know how to do it rigorously :
$\int \exp(-\mathrm{i}\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r})q^{\eta-d}\,\mathrm{d}^dq$, where $\eta$ is a real number, and $d$ an integer of course.

Comment: How do you define $q^{\eta-d}$?